# Using catch_that_image() for galleries?

Tags: php, functions, gallery

I'm currently in the process of creating my first custom wp theme, in which the post  contains the title, the content, the gallery, and also a div in between the title and content where as a background image I'd set the first image for the gallery below. 
I have tried using tons of different codes to get the first image from the gallery. Most versions of catch_that_image only work good on normal images, but not on galleries.
I have tried using the function from [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264020/wordpress-snag-first-image-from-a-gallery). It caught the first image good, but destroyed the sites gallery (no idea how it happened, new to this stuff).

Does anybody know a good way to find the first image of a gallery?
Also I'd really appreciate an easy to get explanation. I'm really a 'just arrived' person here, trying to not go crazy.

Using the latest Wordpress version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gallery is a shortcode, so you will need to parse the shortcode to grab the image referenced therein:

```
function pull_image_from_gallery(){
  global $post;
  $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
  preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches );
  foreach ($matches[2] as $k=>$v) {
    if ('gallery' == $v) {
      $atts = shortcode_parse_atts($matches[3][$k]);
      if (!empty($atts['ids'])) {
        $ids = explode(',',$atts['ids']);
        $first = $ids[0];
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $atts['ids'] );
        if (!empty($image)) {
          // do what you want with image
          return $image[0];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think the code is fairly easy to follow but...

1. [grab the regex that Core uses to extract shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex)
2. If there is a shortcode, [parse the attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex)
3. Grab the first ID and [get the image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) ( or try
   [`get_attachment_image_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) if more convenient )

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the code didnt work. I have pasted it into functions and used  `<img src="<?php pull_image_from_gallery(); ?>" alt="first gallery image"/>`
But it only returned the alt text.

Comment: My code doesn't `return` or `echo` anything. You are using it wrong. See the part where it says `do what you want with image"? That is the part you have to fill in.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. Like I said I'm new to this junk

Comment: @aln447 : see the edit. I made changes to fit the way you are trying to use it. Make sure you re-copy the whole thing.